# Call Woocommerce wc_customer_bought_product methods from a third party plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, user-data

In WooCommerce I am using Boss Learndash plugin and in a template file of this plugin `plugins/boss-learndash/templates/learndash/single-sfwd-course.php`, I am trying to add once more button to users who have bought the course/product. For that Im trying to call wc_customer_bought_product woocommerce function in the template but seems like it is not able to call that function.

I tried by adding `global $woocommerce;` and also tried by `wc->user->wc_customer_bought_product` but couldnt fix it.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`wc_customer_bought_product()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_customer_bought_product.html#190-240) function **is not a method** of any WooCommerce class. It's just a conditional function with 3 arguments `$customer_email`, `$user_id` and `$product_id`:

```
wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $user_id, $product_id );
```

It will return a boolean `true` or `false`, so you will use it in an **`if`** statement as a conditional function.

To get the user ID and the customer email, you can use:

```
// Get the current user data:
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = $user->ID; // Get the user ID
$customer_email = $user->user_email; // Get the user email
// OR
// $customer_email = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'billing_email', true ); // Get the user billing email

// The conditional function (example)
// IMPORTANT: $product_id argument need to be defined
if( wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $user_id, $product_id ) ) {
    echo "Has bought the product";
} else {
    echo "Has not bought the product yet";
}
```